# How to display helptext on hover in apex:Column

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, helptext

I would like to display help icon,on hover display helptext in apex column header.

**Code:**

```
<apex:column HeaderValue="Description" width="24%">
                <apex:outputField value="{!manWrap.manMil.Description__c}" rendered="{!NOT(manWrap.isEdit)}" />
                <apex:inputField styleClass="slds-input" value="{!manWrap.manMil.Description__c}" rendered="{!manWrap.isEdit}"/>
            </apex:column>
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Work around:**
I have used pageBlockSectionItem, but it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove the headerValue property and replace it with a `<apex:facet name="header">`.
Then in the facet you can add your text and icon, with the behavior you want.

see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_facet.htm